# Multi values per hash key

Tags: ruby, hash

Here is an extract from a file I am using for a script:

```
host1 10000000c9c5acfa
host1 10000000c9fc168c
host2 10000000c9c5fb32
host2 10000000c9fc1682
host1 10000000c9c5bf4e
host1 10000000c9fc168d
host3 10000000c9534d61
host3 10000000c9534ffe
host3 10000000c9534d61
host3 10000000c9534ffe
```

I am struggling to create a hash or an array (not sure what is better in this case) so that I have following format

```
host1 10000000c9c5acfa,10000000c9fc168c,10000000c9c5bf4e,10000000c9fc168d
host2 10000000c9c5fb32,10000000c9fc1682
host3 10000000c9534d61,10000000c9534ffe
```

I want to have hosts that show all WWNs in one line, but sometimes hosts have one WWN, sometimes two, and sometimes four. Any idea how I can form a hash/array here?

Comment: Create a hash where key is a host and value is an array.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, can you pls help to write this form ? I am struggling a bit to understand ruby in this sense

Comment: Sure, what do you have so far? And what is the problem with the code?

Comment: As @SergioTulentsev says. For example, `{ :host1 => [1,2,3], :host2 => [4,8] }` etc (I used very small numbers for illustration :)).

Comment: Thank vsp_host = `/usr/bin/cat #{all_wwns}  `
   vsp_host.split("\n").each do | line|
     if line =~ /^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)+\s+(\S+)/
       s = "#{$2}"
       d = "#{$1}"
       s = s.scan(/.{1,2}|.+/).join(".") # add "." for CS in each wwns
                        uniq.store("#{d}","#{s}")
                  arr.push(" #{d}"," #{s}","\n")
      # puts "#{d} \t #{s} "
     end
 end

 for quick review. I am not sure how to even create this.

Comment: vsp_host = `/usr/bin/cat #{all_wwns}  `
   vsp_host.split("\n").each do | line|
     if line =~ /^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)+\s+(\S+)/
       s = "#{$2}"
       d = "#{$1}"
       s = s.scan(/.{1,2}|.+/).join(".") # add "." for CS in each wwns
                        uniq.store("#{d}","#{s}")
                  arr.push(" #{d}"," #{s}","\n")
      # puts "#{d} \t #{s} "
     end
 end

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code. Your code is unreadable in comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would create a `Hash` with `host ⇒ Array[WWN]` pairs:

```
h = {}
File.open("a.txt").each { |l|
  k,v = l.split(' ')
  (h[k] ||= []) << v
}
p h

 # ⇒ {
 # ⇒   "host1" => ["10000000c9c5acfa", "10000000c9fc168c", "10000000c9c5bf4e", "10000000c9fc168d"], 
 # ⇒   "host2" => ["10000000c9c5fb32", "10000000c9fc1682"], 
 # ⇒   "host3" => ["10000000c9534d61", "10000000c9534ffe", "10000000c9534d61", "10000000c9534ffe"]
 # ⇒ }
```

Comment: Thanks here as well. Are you sure this would work ? I got something like below

{"h"=>["o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"]}

Comment: I even have the real output from the terminal test copied. After you have a hash, you can do whatever you want with the result, e.g. `h.keys.each { |host| puts "#{host} #{h[host].join(',')}" }`

Comment: @user2739902 Would you check `l.split(' ') # ⇐` space here? It looks like it was eaten while copy-paste.

Comment: also good. I've just added uniq to your line and Ive got also what i was looking for
h.keys.each { |host| puts "#{host} #{h[host].uniq.join(',')}" }

Comment: One-letter variable names hark back to the days of BASIC; please use something more legible. Also, a single space is the default parameter for `String#split` and can be omitted completely.

Comment: I pity you if you think that `key, value` is more readable that `k,v`. I will not use 100-lettered names where they are totally not legible.

Answer (score 0):

You are right: you need a hash. This code demonstrates.

Calling `split` on each line of the file divides it into whitespace-separated fields. The hash element corresponding to the host is set to an empty array if it soesn't already exist, then the new code is pushed onto it.

The output is generated by dumping the hash, in sorted order of the name of the host, and applying `uniq` to the list of corresponding codes.

```
open('myfile', 'r') do |f|

  data = {}

  f.each_line do |line|
    host, code = line.split
    data[host] ||= []
    data[host] << code
  end

  data.keys.sort.each do |host|
    puts "#{host} #{data[host].uniq.join(',')}"
  end

end
```

**output**

```
host1 10000000c9c5acfa,10000000c9fc168c,10000000c9c5bf4e,10000000c9fc168d
host2 10000000c9c5fb32,10000000c9fc1682
host3 10000000c9534d61,10000000c9534ffe
```

Comment: @user2739902: My apologies; I only recently noticed that you needed duplicate codes removed from the output list. Fixed.

Comment: thanks Borodin. This is exactly what I was looking for b ut my brain for some reason don't understand this logic :)

Comment: @ZDZ: If you explain what part of the code is troubling you then I will explain it better. Basically the hash `data` is keyed by the host names. The value of each element (`data[host]`) is an array of codes that is added to each time a line is read from the file. Once the file has been completely read the arrays in the hash may contain duplicate values, so the output loop uses `uniq` to remove them before joining them into a string with commas.

Answer (score -1):

This will work - please add some fix for removing last ',' in each value:

```
h = {}
lines = File.readlines("a.txt")
lines.each { |line| 
  line = line.chomp
  key,value = line.split(" ")
  if(!h.has_key?(key)) 
    h[key] = ""
  end
  h[key] = h[key] + value + ","
}
print h
```

Comment: You can also look at this page for how to iterate over hashes in Ruby: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F

Comment: Thanks Manoj. This is very close to what I need. What would you do in case wwns are uniq for given key ?

Comment: -1: *"Please add some fix for removing last ',' in each value"* indeed! This is untidy and a little rude. Also `line = line.chomp` is normally written `line.chomp!`, and is unnecessary anyway as you are splitting on whitespace.